# Migrating AdWords to Google Ads. Missing LastReceivedRequestTime field for ConversionTrackerService

Tags: google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

According to [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/services), instead of [ConversionTrackerService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/ConversionTrackerService), we need to use [ConversionActionService](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v9/ConversionActionService).
In our code we using [`lastReceivedRequestTime`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/ConversionTrackerService.ConversionTracker) field from the response, which I can't find at all in the new service. Do I missing something?

Thanks for any help and tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, finally I found this topic: https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/AljDFVYLl7w/m/VdXW1YgRAQAJ

Looks like they just remove fields and it's necessary to request them back, if needed.

**Update**:

*Response from the support:*

Thank you for reaching out to the Google Ads API support team.

With regards to your concern, you can use [metrics.conversion_last_received_request_date_time](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v9/conversion_action#metrics.conversion_last_received_request_date_time) field in the [conversion_action](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v9/conversion_action) resource. Let me know if you have any question.